# Historical Data Test in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Goal:**
Create a view/mostly automated historical data set that shows the number of employees hired at any time - So I expect the data output to be something like:

TABLE - [Dates], [Active Employee Count]

**Method:** So I've constructed the following 2 tables:

- TABLEA - [Dates] <--Contains dates (by day) from 01012014 - 01012016
- TABLEB - [Start Date], [End Date] <--Contains 30000 records of staff start and end dates with a range of other demographic parameters

What I *think* I need to do is construct a CASE/IF statement where:

```
    IF TableA.[Dates] >= TableB.[Start Date]
       AND (TableA.[Date] <= TableB.[End Date] OR TableA.[Date] IS NULL)
           THEN <<count +1 or something>>
              END AS [Active Employee Count]
```

I suppose where I'm stuck is:

- Coming up with the dates in a way that can connect with Table B
- Performing the row by row check
- Each row from TableA performs it's own check and retrieves an "Active Employee Count"

Very open to suggestions around whether i'm structuring this problem wrong ... I suck with time series data so open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Mustafa

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry! SQL-Server.

Comment: How do you plan on using this? Like, do you want to just give it a random date and it tell you how many people worked on that day? I feel a stored procedure may be more appropriate there. If so let me know and I'll post an answer

Comment: Not so much a random date.. The goal is number of people working on any particular day. The particular days are defined by a date range (like 01012014 - 01052016). Each day within that range has a count based on the aforementioned logic, and that count is particular for that day. eg. 1st Jan 2014 active count = 50000, 2nd Jan 2014 = 49998, 3rd Jan 2014 = 50003, etc. Hope this makes sense! Thanks Mr (or Ms) BaconPants

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with "TableA"? Simply do a query against TableB that can take your dates and do the check and call that query when appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(EMPNAME),
        [DATE]
from (
    select  TABLEB.EMPNAME,
            TABLEA.[DATE ]
    from TABLEB 
    cross join TABLEA  
    where TABLEA.[date] >= TABLEB.StartDate 
        and TABLEA.[date] <= TABLEB.ENDDATE
        ) AS T
group by [DATE];
```

Comment: `join` without `on` is not a valid syntax. It looks like there should be the word `on` instead of `where`.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir for pointing out the mistake. I have updated the query.

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much.